# Why do automorphisms of a fixedfield extend to automorphisms of the whole (Galois) field?

Tags: galois-theory

I was thinking about how to prove that if $K/F$ is Galois of Galois group $G$ and $L$ is the fixed field of $H<G$, then the Galois group of $L/F$ is isomorphic to $G/H$. I can easily see that there's an injection of cosets of $H$ into $\text{Gal}(L/F)$, but where I'm stuck is proving that it's surjective. The key seems to be in showing that any automorphism of $L$ (fixing $F$) can be extended to an automorphism of $K$. Why is that the case?

This apparently requires $H$ to be normal to be true, but what bothers me is that I have an argument that only seems to require that $K$ be finite over $F$, without even needing to be Galois and without needing $F$ to be a fixfield. Let $f$ be some automorphism of $F$, and let $K=F(\alpha)$ for algebraic $\alpha$, then the mapping $\sum a_i \alpha^i\to\sum f(a_i)\alpha^i$ is surely an automorphism of $K$, no?

Comment: This isn't true unless $L$ is also Galois, the quotient map only works for normal extensions otherwise $G/H$ is not a group.

Comment: @AdamHughes Is that not built into the fact that $L$ is a fixed field?

Comment: No, take for example $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]{2})$ the subfield $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is the fixed field of complex conjugation (it is the maximal, real subfield) but clearly it is not Galois.

Comment: Here I go riding my hobby horse, but an extensive examination of examples would have told you where you went wrong.

Comment: Wait, well then why is it true that the Galois group of $L/F$ is isomorphic to $G/H$? What assumption am I missing?

Comment: @JackM, $L/F$ is Galois iff $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: I've updated the question.